# Python multi Thread/Queue producer and Consumer race issue

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, queue

I have following python code  with each thread is performing following roles.

Producer- generates json text
Processor- parses the json and generates list of json objects
Consumer- takes the list and persists to a data store

Producer sending the json and consumer getting a list of json, the issue is the message count is not matching from producer to consumer. Some messages are being vanished in-between. I see that message count is in sync between producer and parser though.

Resolved: I had to create new objects after posting them to queue/list. In my previous code I was re-using the list and dict object by just clearing them( May be I was over thinking :)) . This caused object data being cleared in the queue  as it was not consumed yet by downstream threads...

Below is working code

```
import threading
import sys, time
import logging
import random
import Queue, json
from datetime import datetime

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='(%(threadName)-9s) %(message)s', )

MAX_SIZE = -1
producerq = Queue.Queue(maxsize=MAX_SIZE)
consumerq = Queue.Queue(maxsize=MAX_SIZE)


class ProduceJson(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, group=None, target=None, name=None,
                 args=(), kwargs=None, verbose=None, producerq=producerq):
        super(ProduceJson, self).__init__()
        self.target = target
        self.name = name
        self.producerq = producerq
        logging.debug(self.name +" Started")
        return

    def run(self):
        cnt = 1
        try:
            while True:
                #time.sleep(2)
                if not self.producerq.full():
                    timestamp = datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S6Z")
                    item = json.dumps({
                        'seq': cnt,
                        'timestamp': timestamp
                    })
                    logging.debug(self.name + " Posting " + str(item))
                    self.producerq.put(item)
                    cnt = cnt + 1
                    #logging.info(self.name + ' current count : ' + str(cnt))

        except Exception as e:
            logging.error("ERROR " + self.name + e.message)

        return


class ParseJson(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, group=None, target=None, name=None,
                 args=(), kwargs=None, verbose=None, producerq=producerq, consumerq=consumerq):

        super(ParseJson, self).__init__()

        self.target = target
        self.name = name
        self.producerq = producerq
        self.consumerq = consumerq
        logging.debug(self.name +" Started")
        return

    def run(self):
        cnt = 0
        itemlist = []
        try:
            while True:
                #time.sleep(2)
                if not self.producerq.empty():
                    item = json.loads(self.producerq.get())
                    #logging.debug(self.name+" Received "+ str(item))
                    pi = dict()
                    pi['pseq'] = item['seq']
                    pi['ptime'] = item['timestamp']
                    itemlist.append(pi)
                    #
                    if len(itemlist) == 5: # Load lits of 10 elements to queue
                        self.consumerq.put(itemlist)
                        logging.debug(self.name + " Posting " + str(itemlist) )
                        itemlist = []
                    cnt = cnt + 1
                    #logging.debug(self.name + '  current count :  ' + str(cnt))
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error("ERROR " + self.name + e.message)
        return


class ConsumeJsonList(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, group=None, target=None, name=None,
                 args=(), kwargs=None, verbose=None, consumerq=consumerq):
        super(ConsumeJsonList, self).__init__()
        self.target = target
        self.name = name
        self.consumerq = consumerq
        logging.debug(self.name +" Started")
        return

    def run(self):
        cnt = 0
        cl = []
        try:
            while True:
                #time.sleep(2)
                if not self.consumerq.empty():
                    cl = self.consumerq.get()
                    cnt = cnt + len(cl)
                    logging.info(" Consumed items  "+  str(cl) )
                    cl = []
                    #else:
                    #    logging.debug(self.name + '****Is EMPTY**')
                    #
                    #logging.info(self.name + ' current count : ' + str(cnt))
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error("ERROR " + self.name + e.message)
        return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    producer1 = ProduceJson(name='PRODUCER1', producerq=producerq)
    #producer2 = ProduceJson(name='PRODUCER1', producerq=producerq)
    parser1 = ParseJson(name='parser1', producerq=producerq, consumerq=consumerq)
    parser2 = ParseJson(name='parser2', producerq=producerq, consumerq=consumerq)
    #parser3 = ParseJson(name='parser2', producerq=producerq, consumerq=consumerq)
    consumer1 = ConsumeJsonList(name='CONSUMER1', consumerq=consumerq)
    #consumer2 = ConsumeJsonList(name='consumer2', consumerq=consumerq)
    #consumer3 = ConsumeJsonList(name='consumer3', consumerq=consumerq)
    ######
    producer1.start()
    parser1.start()
    parser2.start()
    consumer1.start()
    #consumer2.start()
    #consumer3.start()
```

Comment: What data are you sending and what data are you receiving? An example will make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Producer sending the json and consumer getting a json list, the issue is the message count is not matching from producer to consumer. Some messages are being vanished in-between. I see that message count is in sync between producer and parser though

Comment: Issue has been resolved. The issue was with the code. I was clearing the objects (temlist[:] = [], pi.clear() ) once they are appended to the list/posted to the queue. The moment I clear the object, the data being cleared by the list, because it was still referring to the same object in the list/queue. To resolve I just had to create a new object, which I should have done to begin with.